# How easy is it to swap parts of Rails stack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I read that as you are using the default Rails stack you are happy, but if you try to swap something then the real headache begins.

How hard is it to use jQuery instead of Prototype and Haml instead of ERB?

(I'm not Rails developer, I just trying to collect some info about it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major components in previous versions of Rails were quite tightly-coupled, but Rails 3 makes it easier than ever to "have it your way". In fact, Rails 3 was re-architected with this goal in mind and is much more modular.

- [Rails Myth #3: Rails forces you to use Prototype](http://www.loudthinking.com/posts/32-myth-3-rails-forces-you-to-use-prototype)
- [Rails Myth #4: Rails is a monolith](http://www.loudthinking.com/posts/33-myth-4-rails-is-a-monolith)

Answer (score 0):

I use jQuery on a daily basis in a large Rails app. There's nothing to it, no barrier at all. In fact as far as I can tell from anecdotal evidence (just from talking to local rails devs that I know on other projects, and my perception of general blog trends), jQuery/Rails is becoming one of the most popular pairings.

I don't use Haml, but I know of at least one major Rails project in my area that does and they love it. Again, the trend seems to be heading that direction. So, on both counts, I'd say there's exactly zero barrier to entry.